# What is the purpose of register model in UVM?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

In UVM, the testbench does not have any visibility into the internal registers of the DUT. Then why is there mirroring and creation of Register models in the UVM testbench architecture? What purpose does it serve?

The testbench would not come to know if any status bit etc is ever updated or not inside DUT since it only has access to its input output ports.

Comment: you have wrong assumptions about accessibility. any register or net of a DUT can be accessed from test bench.

Comment: What effect will it have if we don't use register models in our testbench? Is it just to have a reference model for DUT registers or is there any other purpose?

Comment: @Serge So you mean that all the internal registers write and read value can be accessed from the DUT input output ports?

Comment: No, i meant that there are different front door (xmr) and back door (vpi) mechanisms in verilog to access any variable as soon as you know the hierarchical path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DUT may not have direct access internal registers via ports, but some registers are accessible via an interface protocol. The register model is primarily intended for these registers. But you can access any register in the design via the backdoor (but not always desirable as it requires more work to setup and maintain).

The mirror stores the value of what the test-bench *thinks* are the register values of the DUT. When you do a `.mirror()`, the register model compares the register value (actual) verses the mirror (expected).

Status bits are often complicated to predict. To simplify things you can turn off the compare of the field (or register) with `.set_compare(UVM_NO_CHECK)`. If you disable the check at the field level, other fields in the same register will still be compared.

If your ambiances and want to do more complex predictions/mirror-compare on status bits, then you do have the options, such as register callbacks or of extending the `uvm_reg` and `uvm_reg_field` classes to overwrite the `.predict` and `.mirror` methods.

Comment: In the case, none of the registers are visible from the testbench, is there any use of UVM register model then?

Comment: Does Register model always use Backdoor access? I can see from this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/32454818/6641380

Comment: Both frontdoor and backdoor are supported, default is typically frontdoor. https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1d/html/files/reg/uvm_reg-svh.html#uvm_reg.mirror

Comment: Backdoor only is possible. You need to decided if it is worth the effort to develop and maintain. You may have to create a second backdoor map if you are also simulating both RTL and post-synthesis gates.

Comment: Ok I understand that only backdoor access is possible when there is no visibility for any registers. But then is there any need at all for RAL? Is it only for access in 0 simulation time? (is that the only purpose?)

Comment: Backdoor is possible for all register and it accesses the actual register in the DUT. Normally you want to access registers through the frontdoor through a protocol; mimicking physical access. This can let you leverage your simulation tests when your DUT is emulated, FPGA, physical tester (assuming the tool use use support stimulus form simulation).  Backdoor is a *simulation only* way to bypass the protocol so you can load the registers quickly and test the protocol mapping to the registers, and access registers not accessible externally.

Answer (score 2):

UVM RAL provides several benefits

1. It provides high-level abstraction for reading and writing registers in your design. This is especially useful when the RTL for your registers has been compiled from another description. All of the addresses and bit fields can get replaced with human readable names.
2. Your test can be written independent of the physical bus interface. Just call the read/write methods.
3. The mirrored registers make it easy to know the state/configuration of your DUT without having to add your own set of mirrored variables, or perform extra read operations.

Comment: When you mentioned these points, were they referring to front door or backdoor access?

Comment: Also, I had an idea that every interaction between testbench DUT happens on a physical interface level that is why I wanted to know how is RAL in the picture. But now it seems my assumption was partially wrong.

Comment: These benefits are there with either front/back door access. We are trying to raise the level of abstraction writing UVM test benches to transactions. There is not much variation to the timing you can make from a test bench as most of your signals are tied to particular clocks.

Comment: https://verificationacademy.com/sessions/setting-up-register-layer 
https://www.mentor.com/products/fv/multimedia/intro-to-uvm-registers

Comment: Is there any example in the verification academy that goes through a code to actually test DUT registers via RAL?

Answer (score -1):

Register model is an entity that represents the hierarchical data structure of the class object for every register and its individual field. A register model (or register abstraction layer) could be a set of classes that model the memory mapped behavior of registers and memories within the DUT so as to facilitate stimulus generation. we can perform read and write operation on design employing a RAL model. It goes to mirror the design registers by making a model within the verification surroundings. By applying the stimulus to the register model, the actual design registers can exhibit the changes applied by the stimulus.

The advantage of the RAL model comes from the high level of abstraction provided. It provides back door access for registers and memory with easy integration liability in UVM verification environment. Whenever a read or write operation is performed, the RAL Model will be automatically updated. It supports design with multiple physical interfaces.

For more information, use this [link](https://www.agnisys.com/whitepaper-in-pursuit-of-faster-register-abstract-layer-ral-model/).

Thanks,
Mayank